# best practice for create component same views

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface

I have many same UIView in many view controllers .is this best practice that I create component for this view and i use this in other view controllers ? I think that maybe UI/UX Designer will change one of theme at future . is this work right?

for example :

[image]

Comment: Hmm, what do you mean by 'component'?

Comment: that is mean custom view . do i have to make all create all view or i create a custom view for same view and i use it  @Frankie

Comment: Create a `UIViewController` class with your view and subclass it.

Comment: @shallowThought if it will maybe at future ?

Comment: Make a View controller for your component. In your example `shareComponentViewController`. I assume the share controlls will change for the whole app. Than use it a s child view controller.

Comment: @shallowThought why viewController? custom view is a UIVIew and i have to use it in other viewController . so i can create a class of uiview and make custom view and then use other view controllers . right? like above picture ...

Comment: You normally want to encapsulate business logic as well. Handling the tab on the telephone button for instance.

Comment: I think subclassing `UIView` is enough for simple UI elements. I only subclass `UIViewController` when the nature is a modal view controller, for example a UIImagePicker, ContactsPicker.